# Alternate Row Colours on Tables with Inline Style CSS

Tags: css, inline-styles

I want to alternate the background colour of a table to increase readability. After googling a bit I found the code I needed.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

The problem in my solution, I don't have access to head tag, and I want to implement this with inline style CSS, but it doesnt work.

```
<tr style="nth-child(even) background-color: #000000;">
```

Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to the tag?  Inline styles are a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: The first bit of css that you blocked out would belong in your stylesheet if you wanted to change the background color of every other row. The inline code that you wrote won't even work on itself because that particular row would be 'odd', as it would be the 1st child.

Comment: I wrote head tag but since I wrapped it around brackets, it didnt show in my questions. fixed now. The problem is that even if I add the whole table with these tr inline tags, it does not work.

Comment: the 2nd code block makes absolutly no sense at all.

Comment: How to you purpose to write it inline style?

Comment: The question was crystal clear about what @williamwmy wanted. Idk what was the rocket science that people in comment section started digging into deep meaning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inline styles are per-element, so you would have to inject the appropriate styles into the `style` attribute of every other `tr` element. If you're not already generating these rows dynamically, and you cannot use JavaScript to inject these styles, then you're stuck with having to manually apply the attribute on each `tr` element.

Comment: Not stuck, but you'd have to apply the inline style for the background colors on every single row. Tedious, but possible.

Comment: @Tanner: True, I've clarified it now.

Comment: But even if I inject it on every tr, it doesn't work. What I do is that I add <tr style="nth-child(even) background-color: #000000;"> on every row of tr. I thought this would be like, if this row is even, make the background color black.

Comment: You must remove `nth-child(even)` from that lines. That css selector is used to target, in this case, the table row. As you're targeting it already applying inline styles, in this case this selector is not necessary.

Comment: Ah ok, so I cant use the selector to "check" if this line is odd or even. How can I write a inline style that do something like "if this is an even line, apply background colour?

Comment: @williamwmy: That's not possible.

Comment: @williamwmy Al least with pure css you can't. If you don't have access to the `<head>`tag, you can accomplish with the jQuery script I've suggested, inserted directly in the `<body>`tag.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar situation.  I solved it by putting a style section just before my table:

```
<style>
    table#some_table_id tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#dddddd; }
</style>
<table id="some_table_id">
    <!-- table markup removed -->
</table>
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works for me (in Google Chrome 29.0.x).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to BoltClock answer, if you can use jQuery you can try something like this:

```
$('tr:nth-child(even)').css("background", "red");
```

This auto-insert inline styles in your markup.

[A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fK98/)

Answer (score 1):

So, I am actually using React... I wanted to get a table to display the rows in alternating colors. The code uses a lot of inline styling and there are some interesting syntax differences for css, but I thought I would share the piece of code that does it.

I am mapping through an array of lines of a report:

`<tbody>
  <tr key={line.number} style={(line.number % 2) ? { backgroundColor: 'someColor' } : null}>
    ...code table column data here...
  </tr>
</tbody>`

I did find out that I cannot use this code; not because it doesn't work. Since there are lines that get skipped I still end up with rows of the same color next to each other. If I happen to figure that out I will update. For now, I guess I will just use borders.

-L-

Answer (score -5):

Here's what you're looking for, hope it helps.

```css
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #0000335f;
    }
```

```html
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>text1</td>
          <td>text2</td>
          <td>text3</td>
          <td>text4</td>
          <td>text5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The question specifically asks about inline styling.